# Difference Between using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core vs Microsoft.Office.Core

Tags: reference, ms-office

Can you explain me the difference between these two kind of referencing?

```
using Office = Microsoft.Office.Core
              Vs
using Microsoft.Office.Core
```

What is the difference between these two kind of referencing and when should we use one over other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first line is an alias declaration.

When you use that, you should specify the alias (in your case 'Office') as a prefix to any class/object from the Microsoft.Office.Core namespace, for example:

```
private Office.DocumentInspector d = null;
```

Oterwise, you need to either specify the full path to the namespace:

```
private Microsoft.Office.Core.DocumentInspector d = null;
```

or, use the **using** keyword, to tell the compiler to look for classes/objects in that namespace, thus using just:

```
private DocumentInspector d = null;
```

Hope this clears the subject.

Comment: That's exactly what I was searching for. Thanks a lot Nir.